# Make new dataframe from if condition across 2 dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe

If I have a monthly "points" dataframe, in which the values are from cumsum():

```
ID   month1  month2  month3  month4
000  0       10      45      55
111  40      60      100     100
```

And I have a "buy" dataframe, which is basically whether there'll be a purchase in that month or not:

```
ID   month1  month2  month3  month4
000  NO      NO      YES     NO
111  NO      YES     NO      YES
```

How do I make a new dataframe whose values satisfies the condition:

```
IF points > 40 AND buy == "YES" 
THEN returns MAX(40, 0.8*points)
ELSE returns 0
```

the resulting dataframe should be:

```
ID   month1  month2  month3  month4
000  0       0       40      0
111  0       48      0       41.6
```

ID 111's month4 value is 41.6 because it still got 12 points remaining from the previous months and added by another 40 from current month, so it's 52*0.8 = 41.6

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be to merge the two datasets by 'ID':

```
df = df1.merge(df2, on='ID')
```

And then use np.where:

```
df['month1_x'] = np.where((df['month1_x'] > 40) & (df['month1_y'] == 'YES'), MAX(40, 0.8*df['month1_x']), 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `np.where` and assign all columns:

**Prepare:**

```
df1 =pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''ID   month1  month2  month3  month4
000  0       10      45      55
111  40      60      100     100'''),sep='\s+')
df1

df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''ID   month1  month2  month3  month4
000  NO      NO      YES     NO
111  NO      YES     NO      YES     '''),sep='\s+')
df2
df2 = df2.set_index('ID')
```

**Code:**

```
df = df1.set_index('ID') 
condition = (df *0.8 > 40) & (df2== 'YES')
df[df.columns] = np.where(condition, df.values, 0)

df[df.columns] = np.where(df*0.8>0,df,np.nan)
ffill = df.ffill(axis=1) - df.ffill(axis=1).shift(1,axis=1)*0.8

df[df.columns] = np.where(((df.isna())|(ffill.isna())),df,ffill)
df = (df.fillna(0)*0.8).reset_index()
```

**Output:**

```
    ID  month1  month2  month3  month4
0   0   0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
1   111 0.0     48.0    0.0     41.6
```

Comment: sorry for asking more questions how to make it so that the true result is max(df.values*0.8,40)? also is there a way to update the subsequent values (subtract the already 'used' values from the cumsum()) so that it's like in my example? thanks

Comment: Sure i will see it soon.. anyway you can use np.maximum along with df.values * 0.8...

Comment: Just change `df.values` to `np.maximum(df.values*0.8,40)` inside the `np.where` And tell me if it went well.. just not in front of computer..

Comment: is there a way to update values of the subsequent columns accordingly? as in I want to get it to be like this: 
ID 111's month4 value is 41.6 because it still got 12 points remaining from the previous months and added by another 40 from current month, so it's 52*0.8 = 41.6

Comment: so there is another condition that for each "yes" the values id being consumed on the row? after applying 0.8?

Comment: yeah, for every time it's a "yes" and the current value is larger than 40, I want to subtract it according to maximum(df.values*0.8,40), and reflect it to subsequent columns.

Comment: why month3 000 is 0 in the result and not 40?

Comment: can you axplain when exactly you waent to do `*0.8`?

Comment: ah yeah my bad month3 000 should've been 40 >_<.

Comment: I want the updated value if both condition (value > 40 and a "YES") are satisfied to be either 40 or 80% of the value, whichever's larger.

Comment: and my solution doesn’t provide that?